# Control which tick marks / labels appear on x-axis in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to have control over which tick marks appear on the x-axis. The following code places tick marks in a sequence of 5 (at 5, 10, 15 ... 30)

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x =  1:30,
                 y = sample(100:300, size = 30, replace = T))

p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = x, y = y, type = 'line') %>%
      layout(title = 'Example plot')
p
```

I need to place them in a sequence of 6 at 6, 12, 18, 24, 30. I've been browsing the documentation but I cannot seem to find what I need. In `ggplot2` this can be done via `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(6,12,18,24,30)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `style` to add the ticks:

```
p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = x, y = y, type = 'line') %>%
    layout(title = 'Example plot', xaxis = list(autotick = F, dtick = 6))
p
```

[image]

Here are some more examples: https://plot.ly/r/axes/

Comment: I don't think your answer shows an example that answer precisely the question answered. I also have the same question and I can't figure out (unfortunately) from your answer how to customize the x axis.

Answer (score 5):

If you need uneven spacing you can use tickvals, it requires tickmode = "array" as below

```
%>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autotick = F, tickmode = "array", tickvals = c(6,12,24)))
```