# Custom tick marks / labels appear on x & y axis in plotly surface plot?

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, surface, r-plotly

I would like to control the tick marks for the surfaceplot

Using the standard volcano code here for a reproducible code. This is what I tried but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
p <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>%  layout(title = 'Example plot',xaxis = list(autotick = F, dtick = 10))
```

I want the x-axis to be in an increment of 10 and y axis the digits need to be replaced by the words, but I am only looking for 3 ticks here like "Sixty" (instead of 60), "Eighty"(instead of 80) and "hundred" (instead of 100). I have no clue how to deal with the y axis.

In this answer too it says to try this, but it's not working for me.
[Control which tick marks / labels appear on x-axis in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809906/control-which-tick-marks-labels-appear-on-x-axis-in-plotly)

In this, it mentions about adding a suffix but not replacing.
[Plotly in R: format axis - tick labels to percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638590/plotly-in-r-format-axis-tick-labels-to-percentage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question (i.e., I want the x-axis to be in an increment of 10) hard to say since the x axis is from 1 to 4. But for your second question you could try this:

```
plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(scene = list(yaxis = list(
  tickmode = "array",
  nticks = 6,
  tickvals = c(60, 80, 100), 
ticktext = c("Sixty", "Eighty", "Hundred")
)))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you. What to do if I want the x to be an increment of 2 ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing idea.. this works for xaxis =list(autotick = F, dtick = 2). I see less resources in using plotly for 3D, so hard to get started.

Comment: @johnsmith0. You are right it can be difficult. Have you seen this website https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/the-plotly-cookbook.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing.